# save crop image into folder data/data/myAoo/files

Tags: android, image

I have to save a crop image (I used to crop the functionality of android ) in a folder data/data/myapp/files/  !!

I looked up how to do, but can not figure out the right way!

Can anyone tell me where to see, or how?

Thank you!!

Comment: "I used to crop the functionality of android" -- there is no "crop the functionality of android". http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Comment: (Maybe I was not clear saying functionality of android) I have saved an image from the camera, then I cut out part of an image and I saved it, I do not know how to save the cropped this folder  data/data/myapp/files, can you help me?

Comment: "then I cut out part of an image and I saved it" -- how, precisely, did you "saved it"?

Comment: I used  Intent cropIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT,null); After I set different parameters and I invoke startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE); my app shows a rectangle with which I select a part of the image, this cut can be accessed from the onActivityResult method, but then nn know how to save it in the folder data / data / myapp / files

Comment: "I used Intent cropIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT,null);" -- stop right there. As I wrote in my first comment, there is no  "crop the functionality of android". Please read the blog post that I linked to: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Comment: ok I am reading the blog, but the library which the blog suggests , allow me to save in a specific folder??

Comment: Read the documentation for those libraries. Ask their developers your questions if the documentation is insufficient.

Comment: ok, thank you :) I can see why you should not use Intent, but tell me you would know how to save the image data / data / etc? :D